# Dealing with SQL Alchemy sessions.

Tags: python, postgresql, session, sqlalchemy, cherrypy

Currently, my project structure is this:

```
project-name/libs/__init__.py
                 /module-1
                 /module-2
```

I've declared my sqlalchemy session in **init**.py

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://' + configurations.DB_USERNAME + ':' + configurations.DB_PASSWORD + '@' + configurations.DB_HOST +'/' + configurations.DB_NAME,echo=True)
sm = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=True, autocommit=False,
    expire_on_commit=True)
session = orm.scoped_session(sm)
```

And then I use this session wherever I need to do a query.

Currently, I'm facing this issue:

```
This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (DataError) invalid input value for enum exchange: "BS1"
```

I've not done this query yet. I've changed my database but the error persists. So, I presume the session persists. I've tried flushing the session/rolling back, but nothing helps.

My other problem is that I'm never closing the session. How do I go about achieving that? (It is a web-app)

Answer (score -1):

To be in the safe side, create a new session prior to each usage of the database, Also put your code in try and catch the exception with session.rollback() and session.flush() in the finally.

To fix your problem now , restart mysql server

Comment: Restarting my postgres server doesn't help.